# Cypress is unable to find `textarea` to enter a text while trying to copy a column of a table to another column

Tags: cypress

this is the HTML code

```html
  <td class="primary">...</td>
  <td editable-resource res="res" class="editable-resource ng-isolate-scope" 
    data-ng-class="{'lang-missing': res.missing, 'lang-outdated': res.outdated}">
    <span class="resource-text ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" lang="res.comparison.language" data-rtl
    style="display: block;" xpath="1"> This </span>
    <textarea style="height: 30px; display: none;"
      class="lang-resource resource-input ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" 
      data-ng-model="res.comparison.text" lang="res.comparison.language" data-rtl>
    </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- end ngRepeat: res in data, resourceComparison. resources | filter: resourceComparisonTableFilter -->
<tr data-ng-repeat="res in data. resourceComparison. resources | filter: resourceComparisonTableFilter" class="ng-scope"> 
  <td class="resource ng-binding">...</td>
  <td class="primary">
    <span class="primary-resource ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" lang="res.primary.language" data-rtl>...</span>
  </td>
  <td editable-resource res="res" class="editable-resource ng-isolate-scope" 
    data-ng-class="{'lang-missing': res.missing, 'lang-outdated': res outdated}">
  </td>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to copy the data from Primary Language
the column on the right.

this is the code attempted. So when i run the script, after the click it reloads the table.it doesn’t fail, but I doesn’t see the `textarea`. cypress inform that tesxtarea is hidden and unable to find it.

````
    cy.log('Getting text from cells')
    cy.get(
      '.mls-comparison-table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(2)'
    ).each(($el, index) => {
      const txt = $el.text()
      textData.push(txt)
      cy.log(txt + ' >> ' + index + ' >> ' + textData[index])
    })

    cy.contains('general,name')
      .should('be.visible')
      .parent('tr')
      .within(() => {
        /*
        cy.get('td.primary').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('td.editable-resource').should('be.visible')
        */
        cy.get('td')
          .eq(2)
          .should('be.visible')
          .find('textarea')
          .should('be.visible')
          .click()
          .type('Some String', { delay: 50, force: true })
      })```



this is the cypress test result
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL3XQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV8Db.png
````

Comment: Please add the code to the question and avoid using screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 2):

The "detach from DOM" and the fact you cannot find the `textarea` suggests that the cell is changed when the user interacts with it, i.e view mode / edit mode.

Maybe the test sequence below will catch it.

You can also add `{force:true}` to the type, since `textarea` has `display:none`,

```html
<textarea style="height: 30px; display: none;"...
```

but that may change when edit mode is activated.

**Try this**

```js
cy.contains("td", "general,name")
  .parent("tr")
  .within(() => {

    /*
      go into edit mode
      see if one of these will do it
    */ 
    cy.get("td").eq(2).focus()  
    //cy.get("td").eq(2).click()  
    //cy.get("td").eq(2).focus().click()  

    cy.get("td").eq(2).find("textarea")
      .should('not.have.css', 'display', 'none')  // try with and without
      .type('String', {force: true})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains("td", "general,name")
  .should("be.visible")
  .parent("tr")
  .within(() => {
    cy.get("td")
      .eq(2)
      .should("be.visible")
      .find("textarea")
      .click()
      .type("Some String", { delay: 50 })
  })
```

Comment: @Rita Basu-ghosh I have updated my answer. Please check.